# git eclipse synchronize workspace shows too many incoming changes due to line endings

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In Windows, I'm using the `egit` plugin freshly upgraded to the 20120613 version.

`git status` and `git diff` on the command line show the correct uncommitted changes.

In Eclipse the *Project Explorer* shows correctly the projects and files that have modifications.

**UNFORTUNATELY:**

If I right-click on a project and select *Team / Synchronize Workspace* it shows ALL the files changed.

If I right-click on a changed file and select *Compare With / HEAD Revision* it shows the entire file changed, I have to make it ignore whitespaces to show the actual relevant changes.

I have `core.autocrlf=true` in the global configuration, in my user's configuration, and Eclipse *Preferences* agrees with this too. (I do not override it in the repo.)

The project comes from a `git svn clone`, if that matters. Normalizing all the line endings and committing back to the main project is not an option either. The problem is clearly not with git but with the egit plugin. And only in Team Synchronize, otherwise it's working fine.

I'm actually trying to sell the idea of using git instead of Subversion, but if the Team Synchronization doesn't work well, it's a huge disadvantage compared to using Subversion.

**UPDATE**

In the latest version of the plugin the problem seems to be solved. I just migrated my workspace to Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), installed egit, and now *Synchronize Workspace* seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066914/can-git-svn-be-made-to-handle-crlf-like-native-subversion-clients) since it doesn't aware about Eclipse, but I believe something there may be applicable to your case.

Comment: Thanks, that's informative. It doesn't help me though, because I cannot normalize and rewrite the entire repo, and I definitely don't want an svn checkout at the same time with git.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed in the latest version of the plugin. Or perhaps it may also have to do with my migrating to Eclipse 4.2 (Juno).

Comment: I have the same problem on Eclipse 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- select all files
- right click
- and select "**Add to git Index**"
- Then commit all files and push to server